# where to get the value when sending the request?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

please help to solve the problem.

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="commonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commonModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

                <h4 class="modal-title" id="commonModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default but_cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отменить</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary but_ok" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I send ajax request as follows:

```
$('#commonModalLabel').text('Удалить профиль?');
$('#commonModal .modal-body').html('Возможность восстановить профиль будет доступна в течение двух недель. Для восстановления нужно отправить <a href="mailto:prozaik81-2@yandex.ru">администратору</a> ресурса письмо с почтового адреса, который был указан в профиле.');
$('#commonModal').modal('show');    

$('#commonModal .but_ok').on('click', function(){
    console.log('ok');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/accounts/delete_profile/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.result == true){
                $('#mySmallModalLabel').text('Профиль удалён');
                $('#infoModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });             
});
```

views.py:

```
def delete_profile(request):
    result = False

    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')     

        try:
            entry = User.objects.get(username=username) 
            entry.is_active = 0
            entry.save()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            result = True

    data = {
        'result': result,       
    }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

the problem is that in the log, the following error message:

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):
>   /accounts/delete_profile/

in the case of a form, I'd send the token as follows:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

but in my case there is no form (!). please tell me where to get the token and how to send

Comment: Javascript is probably not sending your CSRF token. You should probably add it to the `data: {}` attribute in your `ajax()` call. You can get it from the MataTag.

Comment: and where to get this value? I also do not form

Comment: Check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your AJAX request.

```
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
    },
```

Sometimes it does not work in some browsers (in my case it is chrome), so you can add these to data you are sending to view:

```
data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $.csrf_token;
```

`$.csrf_token` is a global object for me, I put token printing it to template directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.csrf_token = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
```

Comment: I send сsrf this way. not described here is to save space

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is explained in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Be aware, that if no form is rendered django might not send a csrf token, you'll have to use the ensure_csrf decorator